# Add directory before word contain extension .txt

Tags: command-line, squid, acl

I have a file named acl.txt

```
acl test1 dstdomain web.txt
acl test2 dstdom_regex domain.txt
acl test3 dstdomain .facebook.com
http_access deny test1
http_access deny test2
http_access deny test3
```

This is the result i am finding, add "/etc/squid" before word.txt.
Sample below:

```
acl test1 dstdomain "etc/squid/web.txt"
acl test2 dstdom_regex "etc/squid/domain.txt"
acl test3 dstdomain .facebook.com
http_access deny test1
http_access deny test2
http_access deny test3
```

If is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` and the substitution operator: `s|old|new|`:

```
$ sed -E 's|\S+\.txt|etc/squid/&|' file
acl test1 dstdomain etc/squid/web.txt
acl test2 dstdom_regex etc/squid/domain.txt
acl test3 dstdomain .facebook.com
http_access deny test1
http_access deny test2
http_access deny test3
```

The `\S+` will match one or more non-whitespace characters, so `\S+\.txt` will match any strings that contain no whitespace and end with `.txt`. Note that `.` means "any character" so to match a literal `.`, we need to escape it as `\.`. Then, the special `&` symbol will be replaced by whatever was matched, so `etc/squid/&` will simply add `etc/squid/` before each word ending with `.txt`.

If you want to modify the original file, use `-i`:

```
$ sed -i -E 's|\S+\.txt|etc/squid/&|' file
$ cat file
acl test1 dstdomain etc/squid/web.txt
acl test2 dstdom_regex etc/squid/domain.txt
acl test3 dstdomain .facebook.com
http_access deny test1
http_access deny test2
http_access deny test3
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i ~ "\\.txt$") {$i="etc/squid/"$i}}}1' file
```

- `for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)` will loop over all the fields in the current line.
- `if ($i ~ "\\.txt$")` will check if the current field contains `.txt` at its end ... Then if true ...
- `$i="etc/squid/"$i` will prepend `etc/squid/` to that filed.
- The `1` at the end means print all lines.

The above will print output to the terminal and you can redirect it to a new file with:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i ~ "\\.txt$") {$i="etc/squid/"$i}}}1' file > newfile
```

To modify the original file in-place instead, use:

```
gawk -i inplace '{for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {if ($i ~ "\\.txt$") {$i="etc/squid/"$i}}}1' file
```